# Analysis Question Involving Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So I've been sick and I've missed a couple of lectures of my Analysis class. But I didn't want to be too behind in lecture tomorrow, so I was trying to catch up by reading my textbook and solving some problems.

Here's one I was having some trouble with:

> Prove $\sqrt2\in\mathbb R$ by showing $x^2 = 2$ where $x = A|B$ is a cut w/ $A = \{r \in \mathbb Q : r \leqslant 0 \text{ or } r^2 < 2\}$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you! :)

Comment: This is what he's asking about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut

Although the wording is a bit confusing.

Comment: Actually, what you are going to prove is that _there exists an $x$ satisfying $x^2=2$,_ because that's the only reasonable  definition of $\sqrt{2}$ in the language of fields. Did you check the definition of product of two cuts?

Comment: @Tgymasb $\sqrt 2$ is not obviously in $\mathbb R$, to prove it you need to either construct it as above and prove it correct using the definition of multiplication of Dedekind cuts, or prove something like the Intermediate Value Theorem, again starting from the definition of a Dedekind cut (or your favorite construction of the real numbers). Until you think about it a little, it's not clear there should exist any object at all worth calling a square root of $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $A$ and $B=A^c$. We have to show first that $(A|B)$ is a cut. For this we need to show that for all $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ we have $x\leq y$.

Assume $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. Then, $y>0$ and $y^2\geq2$. If $x>y$ then $x>0$ and it follows that $x^2>xy>y^2\geq2$. Contradiction. Therefore $x\leq y$. Therefore $A,B$  is a cut.

Now consider $(A_1|B_1)=(A|B)^2$, i.e. where $B_1=\{z=y_1y_2:\ y_1,y_2\in B\}$ and $A_1=B_1^c$.

Observe that $B_1\supset \{y>0:\ y\geq2\}$.

Conversely, if $y\in B_1$ then $y=y_1y_2$ with $y_1,y_2\in B$. Therefore $y_1,y_2>0$ and $y_1^2,y_2^2\geq2$. Then $(y_1y_2)^2\geq4$ and $y_1y_2>0$. Therefore $y_1y_2\geq2$. Hence $B_1=\{y>0:\ y\geq2\}$. This is, $(A_1|B_1)=2$.

Comment: I get it now! Thanks so much, Carol!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

I think that you have to apply the definition of *Dedekind cut*, which must be "something like" :

> Let $D \subseteq \mathbb Q$ be a set. The set $D$ is a *Dedekind cut* if the following
>   three properties hold :
>
> > a. $D \ne \emptyset$ and $D \ne \mathbb Q$.
> >
> > b. Let $r \in D$; if $y \in \mathbb Q$ and $y \ge r$, then $y \in D$.
> >
> > c. Let $r \in D$; then there is some $y \in D$ such that $y < r$.

---

With your symbolism, we have to consider $A|B$ where $B=A^C$ and apply the above definition with $B$ in place of $D$.

---

See :

- Ethan Bloch, [The real numbers and real analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=r0qcU9U2_I4C&pg=PA33) (2011), **Ch.1.6 Dedekind Cuts**, page 33-on.

Comment: Thank you so much for linking me to the book, Mauro. Took a look and it's super helpful :)

And thank you for your hint too.