# Analysis Question Involving Real Numbers and Sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've been sick and I've missed a couple of lectures Analysis. But I didn't want to be too behind in lecture, so I was trying to catch up by reading my textbook and solving some problems.

Here's a question I was having some trouble with:

Prove $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ because $x^2=2$ where $x=A\mid B$ is a cut in $\mathbb{Q}$ with $$A=\{r\in \mathbb{Q}: r\le 0 \text{ or } r^2<2\}.$$

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you! :)

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141559/analysis-question-involving-real-numbers-prove-that-sqrt2-in-mathbb-r?rq=1). Do not ask the same question twice.

Comment: Oh. I'm sorry Dietrich! I'm new to this site and didn't know I couldn't do that...

I thought my old question had gotten lost here since I asked it so late last night

Comment: If there's a way I can delete this, let me know! I'll be more than happy to :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your notation, but can you show that for every element $u$ of the cut, you have $u^2 - 2 < 0$ and for every $v$ not in the cut, you have $v^2 - 2 > 0$, and can you show that the cut, as defined, is actually a cut? (In particular, you need to show that both $A$ and $B$ are nonempty. I'm not certain what else is required offhand -- probably that if $u \in A$ and $u ' < u$, then $u' \in A$, and a corresponding statement for $B$.)

Comment: That, and that $(A|B)^2=2$.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks, Carol.

Comment: Actually $u^2-2<0$ does not hold for every element $u$ of the cut; for instance it fails for $u=-5$. It does hold for every non-negative element of the cut though.

Comment: @JohnHughes, would you mind to move your answer to the question linked by Dietrich? Actually, this is an almost exact duplicate (by the same OP!). The older post is edited and has a better shape, I guess. (I'm also new here, I'm asking something reasonable?)

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf: Your question seems reasonable.

Comment: Since Carol's answer in that related question is a much better version of my answer -- she not only fills in details, but gets them right! -- I'm going to leave mine here to wither and die if OP eventually deletes the question.